# Mail Merge Dynamically Generated Table

Tags: mailmerge, dynamic-tables

In one of our letters that we are generating using the mail merge, we also need to dynamically generate a table which populates it's table rows with the output from SQL server in csv format, so that each value from the output fits into each cell of the table.

It works fine but the problem comes into the picture where we need to populate a column of currency values. We are able to populate the values as it is but if we format the numbers in thousands in SQL(separated by comma), then the mail merge considers that as the delimiter and it splits the values (say 1,001,34 into 1,001, and 34 in three different cells). Is there any alternative fix for this one? like an escape sequence that probably skips the commas used for formatting the amount value? Below is the code example.,

%TABLE%%STYLE:TableStyle1%«SchemeDetails_SchemeName» (Column Header 1),(Column Header 2),(Column Header 3)%ENDROW%«InvestmentHoldings_csvlist»%ENDTABLE%

Also this code automatically generates an empty row right between the header and the data rows which also needs to be avoided. But then the formatting of the numbers is the major issue we are trying to fix at the moment.

Could anyone help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file should have the plain numbers, without thousands separators. Field switches in the mailmerge main document can then be used to manage the formatting. For example, to output a dollar amount with the $ symbol, a thousands separator, and cents, you might use:

{MERGEFIELD MyData # "$,0.00"}

For more details, see *Mailmerge Number & Currency Formatting* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Thanks for responding,but the problem in using the suggested solution is here in place of the Data row '«InvestmentHoldings_csvlist»' there is not gonna be just currency fields but there are a couple of non-currency fields too., example below

2019/2020,£37,510.08,£7,547.98,S365T%ENDROW%
2020/2021,£25,505.52,£5,333.17,S329T%ENDROW%

So when it renders in the word document the already formatted numbers from the sql are splited further by the actual delimiter of comma of word. So it's difficult to use # "$,0.00" in this case. I know it's tricky. Do you have any alternate solution for this?

Comment: also, the values are not fetched from a .csv file but from the sql server in .csv format

Comment: Evidently, then, whatever you're using doesn't use Word's mergefields. You will need to study the documentation for the product you're using for the %TABLE%%STYLE:TableStyle1% ... %ENDTABLE% code and work with its methods. For example, there might be something along the lines of *Format([Column Header 2],'£#,##0') AS \`Paid\`*.

Comment: Thanks, I would love to but I am not able to trace the proper documentation for this. Also, it uses Mergefield in the data row (MERGEFIELD XXXX_csvlist). I was wondering if there is any escape character for comma in the word MERGEFIELD which tells the program not to consider the next comma as the split delimiter.

Comment: Word MERGEFIELDs have no such parsing capabilities. Nor does Word have a MERGEFIELD that outputs multiple data fields in a tabular format - that is evidently something supplied by the software you're using. When Word's field code display is toggles on, a MERGEFIELD would look like {MERGEFIELD XXXX_csvlist} - Note the braces (which can't be typed) instead of the parentheses you're showing.